# Slow performance with WAMP localhost access from other devices

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, apache-http-server, localhost, wamp

I setup a localhost WAMP server and other device can access my localhost site on my win8 laptop with computer name instead of IP (because the wireless router is configured with DHCP and the laptop gets its IP using DHCP). However, problem is that the website (WordPress), access speed is extremely slow on other devices other than my localhost computer, usually a 3s task take at least 10 seconds. (i.e. view my localhost site with computer name in a phone within the same wireless network.) Is that normal?
What could be the reason causing it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. Please note, accessing over Wifi(Wireless) than that of accessing through Ethernet (Wired).This is because of the way Wireless Protocol works.
2. There are other reasons that can impact, like you network is busy with other stuff, such as active downloading/uploading going on. For Example Torrents, Automatic Updates either Laptop or Mobile or both.
3. The Laptop you are using is heavily loading or not performing well. Reasons can be you have resource intensive programs running like IDE (Development Environment), Virtual Machines, Too many Browser Tabs, Copying of files etc.

Below are my suggestions:

1. Connect your Laptop running WAMP directly to the Router using Ethernet (Wired Medium).
2. Try to Connect one other laptop/desktop to the Router using Wired Medium and test for the speed. Mobiles have limited power to process, and hence you will not get a good understanding of how well your website is performing.
3. Define correct performance metrics to breakdown the scope of problem. Since 10s has various things included like - time required by Apache to process query, Connect to database if any, Rendering of page on device, Network latency from mobile to router, router to Laptop and vice versa. Using these metrics you can better optimize the complete setup.